# Attaching tr inside a table reusable component

Tags: reactjs, children

i have a table component

Table Component

```
       <table>
         <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>{this.props.th1}</th>
              <th>{this.props.th2}</th>
              <th>{this.props.th3}</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
      </table>
```

Inside the App.js i am calling the Table Component ,

```
               <Table th1="one"  th2="two" th3="three">
                  <tbody>
                      <tr>
                        <td>sample 1</td>
                        <td>sample 2</td>
                        <td>sample 3</td>
                      </tr>
                   </tbody>
                </Table>
```

But i am not able to see the tbody inside the Table, how can i do this one.

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot `this.props.children` . Indeed, you are injecting `<tbody />`as a child of `<Table />`:

```
  <table>
     <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>{this.props.th1}</th>
          <th>{this.props.th2}</th>
          <th>{this.props.th3}</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      {this.props.children}
  </table>
```

Comment: Welcome @DILEEPTHOMAS   

Answer (score 0):

`tbody` is passed to the Table component as `children` props and hence you need to change your Table component to render the children as well.

**Why is `tbody` passed as `children` prop to `Table`?**

> In JSX expressions that contain both an opening tag and a closing tag,
>   the content between those tags is passed as a special prop:
>   `props.children`.

You will have to do

```
<table>
     <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>{this.props.th1}</th>
          <th>{this.props.th2}</th>
          <th>{this.props.th3}</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      {this.props.children}
  </table>
```